Frequent beginner's opening mistakes - which is the worst?
A few experiments with LiChess Stockfish. Some frequently occuring bad moves by beginners. Change in the evaluation is given.
1.f3§ -0.8
1.a3 or h3: -0.2
1.e4 e5 2.Qh5 -0.5
1.e4 e5 2.Nf3 Bd6 -0.6
1.e4 e5 2.Nf3 Nf6 3.Nxe5 Nxe4 -0.4

§ Worst single first move but rarely played
Now contrast with King's Gambit: -0.8! Thus: Which is the worst opening error typical for beginners (again, by LiChess evalation drop) which is at least more frequent in the LiChess database than immediate mate by Shepherd, when limiting to ten halfmoves? (I expect 4.Qe2 N~ in the last line. Or maybe stuff like 1.a4 e5 2.Ra3.)
EDIT: Suggested methology (I'd do it myself, if I had the ressources): Fetch a megabase, select all games with one player <1000, select all games with |eval|>2 after only 10 halfmoves. Sort by frequency. While this will not give a totally objective answer (1000? 2?), it will suffice for me.

In my opinion: 1. g4 is worse that 1. f3.

@Lucenaposition: That's not only your opinion. :-) (But the link insisted on f3.)

This is a question, one cannot answer.
There are simply many many checkmates possible in 10 halfmoves and of course much more positions, which are dead lost.
So is an opening now worse, if there are somehow 20 checkmates posssible, when comparing to another opening, where only 5 checkmates are possible?
If we are taking first moves, it is f3 and g4 (only possibilities for mate in 4 halfmoves.

You can still fall into Fool's mate with 1.f4.

true. so f3, f4 and g4 are eqally bad, when it comes to mate in two
